# Show loader while fetching image from gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic-native, ionic4

I am developing an application in ionic v4 in which I need to upload profile picture from the gallery. So for that I am using `@ionic-native/camera` plugin and below is my code:

```js
const options: CameraOptions = {      
      targetWidth: 800,
      targetHeight: 600,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true,
      sourceType: sourceType,
}
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    console.log(imageData);
})
```

The problem statement is that when I select image even the  size of 1mb then also the screen is taking time to render the image and so that time screen is blank and even spinner/loader is also not visible.

I need to place a loader while the image is being processed.

Comment: update your question with the codes. if all you need is for the user to upload an image why not use the File Input type?

Comment: I need user to upload image from the gallery/sd card/ internal memory. So using input type="file" would work?

Comment: yup. just set the accept type to be the type of image file format you need. @KunalKakkad